# iText divide cell horizontal

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I've been trying to split a cell horizontal into two cells (1 column, 2 rows). Alternative it's also okay to add a horizontal separator in a cell. It should look like in the picture below.

[image: example of table with divided cells]

How can I implement this with iText 7 in Java?

Comment: I removed the "you guys" because there are not only guys on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How about doing nothing special in case of those smaller cells but instead using rowspans for the larger ones?

Comment: @mkl I tried this, but it doesn't work as expected. Do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, the more appropriate way to construct such a table is to create the large cells by means of row spans and have the small cells naturally instead of trying to create the small cells by individually partitioning large cells.

This can be done like this:

```java
try (   PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(RESULT_STREAM_OR_FILE);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument)   )
{
    Table table = new Table(new float[] {30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30});

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("Text")));
        table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("Text")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("Text")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("Text")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell(2, 1).add(new Paragraph("Text")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));

        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
        table.addCell(new Cell().setHeight(15));
    }

    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
}
```

*([CreateTable](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/CreateTable.java#L267) test `testCreateTableForDennis`)*

The result looks like this:

[image: scrren shot]

---

<sub>*The test code has been tested with iText 7.1.4-SNAPSHOT.*</sub>